# Why my Ubuntu 16.04 can't connect to wired when I change kernel to 4.2

Tags: networking, kernel, ethernet

My computer is a Dell Optiplex 7050.

Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (5) I219-LM

The default kernel of 16.04 is 4.8. It worked well but, my project requires me to change the kernel to version 4.2. So I changed the kernel to 4.2 and although other things are normal, I can't connect to internet.

Comment: Perhaps a more effective solution would be to create a virtual machine for your project.  KVM would probably meet your needs, and you could run it at startup and connect via SSH

Answer (score 2):

Kernel version 4.2 is EOL (End Of Life). This means hardware patches and bug fixes will not be applied to it. If you really need an older kernel hopefully 4.1 which is LTS (Long Term Support) will work for you.

As per [The Linux Kernel Archives](https://www.kernel.org/category/releases.html) these are the LTS kernel versions:

- 4.9 maintained by Greg Kroah-Hartman, EOL: Jan, 2019
- 4.4 maintained by Greg Kroah-Hartman, EOL: Feb, 2018
- 4.1 maintained by Sasha Levin, EOL: Sep, 2017
- 3.16 maintained by Ben Hutchings, EOL: Apr, 2020
- 3.10 maintained by Willy Tarreau, EOL: Oct, 2017
- 3.4 maintained by Li Zefan, EOL: Apr, 2017
- 3.2 maintained by Ben Hutchings, EOL: May, 2018

If you try version 4.1 and it doesn't work for your project, or for the Intel Ethernet chip then the next step would be to get the working Intel driver and force it to load in the kernel.

Please keep us posted on your progress via Question update or commenting below this answer.

*Welcome to Ask Ubuntu*

---

**Update:** May 22, 2017.

OP fount LTS Kernel 4.1.xx with update drivers will not work for current platform. OP has opted to get Ethernet support by compiling new driver. The specific Ethernet card gained support in driver version 21.0 as shown by this screen:

[image: Intel Ethernet 21.0.png]

The latest driver has been downloaded (version 22.3 dated Apr 27 2017) and now the following compile errors are encountered:

```
root@horatio2-OptiPlex-7050:/home/horatio2/e1000e-3.3.5.3/s‌​rc# make install 
Makefile:67: *** Kernel header files not in any of the expected locations.
Makefile:68: *** Install the appropriate kernel development package, e.g. 
Makefile:69: *** kernel-devel, for building kernel modules and try again. Stop.'
```

These errors are likely because only `linux-image` was installed and not `linux-headers`. Exact kernel version number is required from `uname -a` output to install appropriate header version.

Comment: If this answer doesn't work as is, the next step is to download the latest intel ethernet driver (April 27, 2017) from here: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/22283/Ethernet-Intel-Ethernet-Adapter-Connections-CD?product=82185 and try to use it in your 4.2 kernel. I can't duplicate your problem on my current system though.

Comment: I try to install e1000e driver, but I encountered some problems: 
'root@horatio2-OptiPlex-7050:/home/horatio2/e1000e-3.3.5.3/src# make install
Makefile:67: *** Kernel header files not in any of the expected locations.
Makefile:68: *** Install the appropriate kernel development package, e.g.
Makefile:69: *** kernel-devel, for building kernel modules and try again.  Stop.'@WinEunuuchs2Unix. I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: @alexanderchen Could you update your question with the output from `uname -a`?

Comment: horatio2@horatio2-OptiPlex-7050:~$ uname -a
Linux horatio2-OptiPlex-7050 4.1.0-040100-lowlatency #201510261105 SMP PREEMPT Mon Oct 26 11:10:26 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: @alexanderchen that version is from 2016-07-05 and may not have the intel driver you need. Try version 4.1.39 from 2017-04-13 instead which may have your driver already compiled. It's available here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.1.39/

Answer (score 0):

I have installed kernel 4.1 and correspond header, but when I went to install e1000e, I have problem:

```
root@horatio2-OptiPlex-7050:~# cd /home/horatio2/e1000e/e1000e-3.3.4/src
root@horatio2-OptiPlex-7050:/home/horatio2/e1000e/e1000e-3.3.4/src# make install
make -C /lib/modules/4.1.0-040100-lowlatency/build SUBDIRS=/home/horatio2/e1000e/e1000e-3.3.4/src modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.1.0-040100-lowlatency'
  CC [M]  /home/horatio2/e1000e/e1000e-3.3.4/src/netdev.o
In file included from /home/horatio2/e1000e/e1000e-3.3.4/src/e1000.h:32:0,
                 from /home/horatio2/e1000e/e1000e-3.3.4/src/netdev.c:48:
/home/horatio2/e1000e/e1000e-3.3.4/src/kcompat.h:763:2: error: #error UTS_UBUNTU_RELEASE_ABI is too large...
 #error UTS_UBUNTU_RELEASE_ABI is too large...
  ^
scripts/Makefile.build:258: recipe for target '/home/horatio2/e1000e/e1000e-3.3.4/src/netdev.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/horatio2/e1000e/e1000e-3.3.4/src/netdev.o] Error 1
Makefile:1383: recipe for target '_module_/home/horatio2/e1000e/e1000e-3.3.4/src' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/horatio2/e1000e/e1000e-3.3.4/src] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.1.0-040100-lowlatency'
Makefile:247: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

Comment: horatio2@horatio2-OptiPlex-7050:~$ uname -a
Linux horatio2-OptiPlex-7050 4.1.0-040100-lowlatency #201510261105 SMP PREEMPT Mon Oct 26 11:10:26 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux